# oracle dml where length >= all (select length from river)

Tags: jquery, oracle

I followed my professor's slide. in his slide,

Find the students with the largest number of semesters.

```
select name
from students
where sem >= all (select sem from students)
```

And I tried this,

```
select name
from river
where length >= all (select length from river)
```

why it it not showing anything? Why the longest river doesn't show?
When I use all, no matter if it is `>=,>,=,<,<=`, it shows nothing.
When I use any,

I tried

```
select name
rom river
where length >= any (select length from river)
```

it shows all river names. (make sense)
I tried this,

```
select name
from river
where length > any (select length from river)
```

It shows all river names without the shortest river. (make sense).

What is wrong with `all`, why it shows nothing in my computer?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYAxa.png)

Comment: my friend tells me because i have river whose length is null, then it shows nothing, what's wrong with null?

Comment: [This doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm) says: to test for nulls, use only the comparison conditions `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. If you use any other condition with nulls and the result depends on the value of the null, then the result is `UNKNOWN`. So `length >= NULL` is `UNKNOWN`, which is not `TRUE`.

Comment: How can I filter out those rivers whose length is null?

Comment: select name
from river
where length is not null and length >= all (select length from river)

Comment: this one doesn't work

Comment: Yep, I see. I posted a detailed answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to know how exactly `ALL` works. [This link says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions002.htm), that it compares a value to every value in a list or returned by a query and must be preceded by `=, !=, >, <, <=, >=`. It also can be followed by any expression or subquery that returns one or more values and evaluates to TRUE if the query returns no rows.

Fine. Imagine looking over the rows one by one checking if its `length` is larger then `length` of all other rows. But now you say there can be nulls in `length`. Ok. [This link says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm): to test for nulls, use only the comparison conditions `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. If you use any other condition with nulls and the result depends on the value of the null, then the result is `UNKNOWN`. So `length >= NULL` is `UNKNOWN`, which is not `TRUE` and all the rows get filtered, because there simply isn't a row for which ALL-clause evaluates to `TRUE`.

Yes, you can exclude rows with `NULL` lengths from comparison.

```
select name
from river
where length >= all (select length from river where length is not null)
```

But finally, I want to say, that you don't need to use `ALL` here in the first place. If you need row with maximum length, just rank your resultset.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   (
  select name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY length DESC NULLS LAST)   RNK
  from students)
WHERE RNK = 1
```

Or you can use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` if you want to keep ties.